# Is there a way to have a static private IP for Lambda in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda for which 'Enable VPC' is turned ON. Currently, The Lambda connects to a EC2 instance and make HTTP calls successfully.

Now, the problem is that the application (Tableau) on the EC2 instance requires a fixed list of IPs (allow list) from which the request should come or it gives a DENY. As the Lambda's private IP keeps changing, it cannot be put in the allow list.

Current solution which is also failing:

Put an ALB in between Lambda and the EC2, and provide the ALB url to the application's allow list. Problem is, after a few days, the two internal private IP addresses of the ALB change automatically and then the application starts giving DENY. So even if we provide a URL in allow list, it actually maps the IPs associated with that URL in the background when we hit save.

So looking for a MINIMAL COST solution to this issue.

Note: All resources have to stay in the private subnet and not exposed to the internet.

Comment: `As the Lambda's private IP keeps changing, it cannot be put in the allow list.` why do you say this? the lambda function has a network interface associated to it so its ip will not be changing

Comment: Cannot you use CIDR range? rather than individual ip?

Comment: Its your Tableau's issue, not the lambda. So you should be asking the question, how to make tableau accept connections from a given subnet/vpc instead.

Comment: @Paulo, IPs were changing when function was re-deployed. I tried again today and I see every time I change code and re-deploy, IP switches. Interesting part is I see two IPs in total and with every re-deployment IP is set to either of the two. So does it mean lambda has two IPs?

Comment: @brushtakopo, App does not allow that :(

Comment: @Marcin, true, I have raised support ticket with Tableau as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Nitesh the lambda will have two network interfaces, one per availability zone I think, so yes two IPs

Comment: @Paolo, just observed that a third IP got assigned to the lambda :(  I guess it will always keep changing to any IP in the subnet. The question still stands.

Comment: @Nitesh you must be doing something in the deployments that causes the network interfaces to change

Comment: You could maybe create a small subnet to contain just this Lambda function and then allowlist the subnet IPs (or CIDR). Be sure it's large enough to accommodate all the Lambda functions you're likely to see invoked concurrently.

Comment: @Paolo I was just adding and removing print statements for re-deployments so not sure why interfaces changed.

Comment: @jarmod yeah will see how viable that is. Thanks.